# Xamarin store multiple data in Variable

Tags: json, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have my code, where i fetch data from a url and parse that data with json.

```
public async void GetItems()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("URL");

        response = await httpclient.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var JsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(JsonContent);

            foreach (var data in jArray)
            {
                var latitude = data["latitude"];
                Console.WriteLine(latitude);
            }

        }
    }
```

in this code I get all my data and print them into the console.

I have a class with the variables i want to set

```
public class FetchedObjects
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }

}
```

How can I store each data from my jArray into these variables? I want to have access to these from my ios or android project.

**EDIT** 
I have some values in json, which are null. How can i handle these, while creating the list? My App crashes, it says :

> Error setting value to 'valuename' on 'App.FetchedObjects'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it code:

```
 List<FetchedObjects> list = jArray.ToObject<List<FetchedObjects>>();
```

**Edit**

in pcl library create class:

```
 public class YourClass
 {
    public async  Task<List<FetchedObjects>> GetItems()
    {
       ....
       if(jArray != null)
       {
          List<FetchedObjects> list = jArray.ToObject<List<FetchedObjects>>();
          return list;
       }
       else
       {
          return null;
       }  
    ...
 }
```

Add reference to  pcl library in your ios and android projects and Use class YourClass

Comment: well how do i reference to that list and get the data from that list? Im new to xamarin so some things are kinda new for me.

Comment: Use it code in pcl library. Add reference to  your pcl library in ios and android project. Do you use Xamarin forms? It helps to use common code.

Comment: No i dont use forms. i want to get data in shared code reference so i cant access the data in android and ios. Thanks for help i will give that one a try. But i dont rly get where my list is saved now

Comment: do you know how to handle null in that list that i create? My App crashes because null can occur in variables. I searched all day but nothing works what i have tried

Comment: I added in my answer logic  with null.

Comment: this actually won't help because my jArray won't be null but a variable e.g. name can be null in that jArray.

Comment: I do not understand it. Add try .. cath to get GetItems() and check result to null(in your Android or iOS projects). Hope this help.